# Enable dotnet feature flag Visual Studio Code

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, flags

I would like to know, how I can enable the dotnet feature flag in VSC. I am programming an extension and therefore I need some variables from datatype dotnet.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Check above link
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery

Comment: Ok, I thought that I can use a command, which enables the flag. Do you know whether something like this exists? I do not want ti install an extra extension...